# How to create clean url using .htaccess for multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess code to rewrite clean url.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+download\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ download/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]+)/?$ download.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This code works fine for single parameter in url. For example it rewrites `www.mysitename.com/download.php?id=123` to `www.mysitename.com/download/123`

But when I tried to pass multiple parameters in url, all I got are errors. Searched various resources and related questions but didn't got proper solution.

I need a url like `www.mysitename.com/download/123/file-name` instead of `www.mysitename.com/download.php?id=123&name=file-name`

I guess I've to use something thing like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ download.php?id=$1&name=$2`. But while implementing I'm getting 404 error. How can I alter My code to pass multiple urls. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a parameter in your rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+download\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ download/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^download/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ download.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to validate my answer in order to mark your question as solved